# How to count unique elements in the array? Need only idea

Tags: java, arrays, unique, element

For example: `String[] str = {"M1","M1","M1","M2","M3"};`
The most recommended is the answer - `HashSet`. Which methods or you have better idea?

Comment: What part of using a set do you not like?

Comment: Absent any external constraints (e.g., "preserve the original order of the unique elements", "do not use builtins", or "do not consume any additional memory"), a HashSet would be my recommendation too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you want to implement this yourself, a `Set` is the way to go. A set will only allow unique elements to be added and will automatically filter duplicates.

The HashSet functionality works as follows:

The hash is computed for the object. Next the set checks if any of the objects with the same hash-value `.equals()` the new value. If so, the new value is ignored. If not, it is added to the set.

If you add everything to the set and then ask for its size, you will get the amount of unique elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
new HashSet(Arrays.asList(str)).size();
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use things that are already provided natively. Which in your requirement is [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).

You can do the following -

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str));
set.size();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too

```
    String[] str = {"M1","M1","M1","M2","M3"};
    HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
    for(String i:str){
        map.put(i, i);
    }
    System.out.println(map.keySet().size());
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a temporary list as in other answers, you can also use:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<> ();
Collections.addAll(set, str);
int countUnique = set.size();
```