# How to condensely compare four different strings to see if there are any matches?

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

I'm creating a slot machine with four possible outcomes. If there are two matches, message2 prints; three matches, message3 prints; four matches, message4 prints.

I understand not all of the code is efficient, but what I'm trying to get at is to condense (or replace) my nested if statements. How would you have done it?

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.util.Random ;

/**
 *Description: Slot machine simulator.
 *
 * @author KO
 */
public class SlotMachine {
public static void main(String [] args) {

    //delcaring variables
    int      repeat     = 0 ;

    //welcoming
    System.out.println("Welcome to the slot machine sim!") ;

    //loop for slot machine
    do {
        //declaring variables
        double   bet        = 0 ;
        int      i          = 0 ;
        int      select     = 0 ;
        String   message0   = null ;
        String   message2   = null ;
        String   message3   = null ;
        String   message4   = null ;
        String[] outcome    = new String[4] ;
        String[] possible   = {"CHERRIES", "ORANGES", "PLUMS", "BARS" } ;

        Random  random      = new Random() ;
        Scanner keyboard    = new Scanner(System.in) ;        

        //ask for bet
        System.out.println("\nHow much are you betting?") ;
        bet = keyboard.nextDouble() ;

        //set messages
        message0   = "\n\nZero matches. You won $0." ;
        message2   = "\n\nTwo matches. You won $"   + (bet * 2) ;
        message3   = "\n\nThree matches. You won $" + (bet * 3) ;
        message4   = "\n\nFour matches. You won $"  + (bet * 3) ;

        //creating white space
        System.out.println(" ") ;

        //randomizer
        for (i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            select     = random.nextInt(possible.length) ;
            outcome[i] = possible[select] ;
        }

        //print outcome
        for (i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
            System.out.print(outcome[i] + " ") ;
        }

        //compare
        if (outcome[0].equals(outcome[1])) {
            if (outcome[0].equals(outcome[2])) {
                if (outcome[0].equals(outcome[3])) {
                    System.out.println(message4);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(message3) ;
                }
            } else if (outcome[0].equals(outcome[3])) {
                System.out.print(message3) ;
            } else {
                System.out.println(message2) ;
            }
        } else if (outcome[0].equals(outcome[2])) {
            if (outcome[0].equals(outcome[3])) {
                System.out.println(message3) ;
            } else {
                System.out.println(message2) ;
            }            
        } else if (outcome[0].equals(outcome[3])) {
            System.out.println(message2) ;
        } else if (outcome[1].equals(outcome[2])) {
            if (outcome[1].equals(outcome[3])) {
                System.out.print(message3) ;
            } else {
                System.out.println(message2) ;
            }
        } else if (outcome[1].equals(outcome[3])) {
            System.out.println(message2);
        } else if (outcome[2].equals(outcome[3])) {
            System.out.println(message2) ;
        } else {
            System.out.println(message0) ;
        }

        //restart application
        System.out.println("\n\nWould you like to play again? (1 or 2)"
                + "\n1. Yes"
                + "\n2. No") ;
        repeat = keyboard.nextInt() ;
    } while (repeat == 1) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want the count of distinct String in an array? Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060229/how-to-count-unique-elements-in-the-array-need-only-idea

Comment: Sort `outcome`, and just find the largest number of consecutive equal element.

Answer (score 0):

You may create Map which contains number of equal values like so:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
int maxRes = 0; 
for(o in outcome) {
  if(!result.contains(o)) {
     result.put(o, 1);
  } else {
     result.put(o, result.get(o)+1);
  }
  maxRes = Math.max(maxRes, result.get(o));
}

// TODO: output according to maxRes value
```